# WPF Key_Down Event

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a wpf application. I need to handle key_down event for main window. If a textbox element is focused, window's key_down event doesn't fire. But key_up event works properly (respectively textbox's and window's events fire). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Preview_Key_Down... (I think that is what it's called).

I'm not a WPF coder, but I think you need to read about Event Tunneling...